# R: Different colors in two-dimensional density plot depending on the values of x and y

Tags: r, colors, plot, density-plot

I am plotting the joint density of two variables x and y using **kde2d** and **persp**.

How can I do the following:

1) Depending on the values of x and y, I want to colour the plot differently. I.e. for values x>.5 and y>.5 the color should be blue and for x<=.5 and y<=.5 the color should be red. Currently the whole graph is just blue (see code below).

2) How can I colour the area below the surface (i.e. the probability mass)? I would like to colour it also with blue and red respectively.

```
library(MASS)
    i<-1
    x<-NULL 
    y<-NULL 
    while (i<=30) {
      x1 <- rnorm(1, 0, 1)
      x2 <- rnorm(1, 0, 1)
      x <- c(x, x1)
      y<-c(y,x2)
      i<-i+1 
    }
    den3d <- kde2d(x, y)
    persp(den3d,xlab="Var1", ylab="Var2", zlab="Density", shade = 0.1, col = "blue", box=TRUE)
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Please change your `while` loop to `x <- rnorm(30); y <- rnorm(30)`. It offends my sensibilities. You should never grow an object in a loop like this and keep in mind that most R functions are vectorized.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the first question:

```
x <- rnorm(30)
y <- rnorm(30)

library(MASS)
den3d <- kde2d(x, y)

cols <- c("blue", "red")[(outer(na.omit(filter(den3d$x>0.5,c(1,1), sides=1)),
                                na.omit(filter(den3d$y>0.5,c(1,1), sides=1)),
                                "+")==4) + 1]

persp(den3d,xlab="Var1", ylab="Var2", zlab="Density", 
        shade = 0.1, col = cols, box=TRUE, phi=90)
```

[image]

Note that a facet is only coloured red if its x and y values are > 0.5 in the whole facet range.

I don't think you should do what you describe in the second question. Anyway, `persp` is not designed for that.

**Edit:** What is going on there?

`den3d$x` are the x values for plotting. We need to check for each facet if the x values on both ends are > 0.5. We can do this by calculating the sum of these values. This can be done using `filter` (see `help("filter")` for documentation):

```
filter(den3d$x>0.5,c(1,1), sides=1)
#[1] NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

Logical input values were automatically coerced to 0 and 1 by `filter`. Resulting values of0 indicate > 0.5 at none of the ends, of 1 indicate > 0.5 at one end and of 2 indicate > 0.5 at both ends. The `NA` we need to remove.

We then do this for `den3d$y` as well and calculate the outer sum, which can result in values between 0 and 4. 0 and 4 mean all four borders of a facet are not and are > 0.5, respectively. Values 1 to 3 indicate 1 to 3 borders are > 0.5. We than set all values of 4 (those we want to color "red") to `TRUE` and the others to `FALSE` by using `==`. Since we need values of 1 for `FALSE` and 2 for `TRUE` in order to subset the color vector, we (automatically) coerce the logical values to 0 and 1 and add 1.

That`s it.

Comment: Thanks Roland. Could you briefly explain your solution. I.e. (1) What is the purpose of the **c(1,1)** argument in **filter** (2) and what purpose does **"+")==4)** in **outer** have and (3) why is +1 added?